# How can I fetch SQLite data using a Adapter in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, adapter

Good day, I want to fetch my database data using an Adapter and display it in my RecylcerViewer. But I don't know how to implement it. Hoping that you will guide me how to accomplish these task

I want to replace these data to my database data but I don't know how to do it.

```
   //I want to replace this dummy data to my database data
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"Dummy Data1", "Dummy Data2"});
```

AccntFragment.java

```
public class AccountsFragment extends Fragment {

    public AccountsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accounts, container, false);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //I want to replace this dummy data to my database data
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"Dummy Data1", "Dummy Data2"}); 
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CardView mCardView;
        public TextView account_type;
        public TextView accnt_description;
        public TextView balance_label;
        public TextView account_balance;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

            account_type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblShareCapital);
            balance_label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblAvailableBalance);

            accnt_description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sl_desc);
            account_balance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actual_balance);

        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.account_type.setText(mDataset[position]);
        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String currentValue = mDataset[position];
                Log.d("CardView", "CardView Clicked: " + currentValue);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

SQliteHandler.java

```
public void addUser(String br_code, String mem_id, String username, String email, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BR_CODE, br_code); // branch code
    values.put(MEM_ID, mem_id); // mem id
    values.put(MEM_USERNAME, username); // username
    values.put(MEM_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(MEM_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_MEMBERS, null, values);

    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "Member's info was inserted successfully: " + id);
    Log.d(TAG, "BR CODE: " + br_code);
    Log.d(TAG, "Member ID: " + mem_id);
    Log.d(TAG, "Username: " + username);
    Log.d(TAG, "Email: " + email);
    Log.d(TAG, "Created at: " + created_at);
    Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------------");
}
/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MEMBERS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("br_code", cursor.getString(0));
        user.put("mem_id", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("username", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));

        Log.d(TAG, "Members's data: " + user.toString());
    }
    else{
        Log.d(TAG, "member's data is empty");
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Member's info was successfully fetch: " + user.toString());

    return user;
}
/**
 * Storing user SL details in database
 * */
public void addUserSLDTL(String sl_desc, String tr_date, String  actual_balance, String available_balance){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SL_DESC, sl_desc); // sl desc
    values.put(TR_DATE, tr_date); // trans date
    values.put(ACTUAL_BALANCE, actual_balance); // actual balance
    values.put(AVAILABLE_BALANCE, available_balance); // availabe balance

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "Members's SL Details was successfully: " + id);
    Log.d(TAG, "SL Desc: " + sl_desc);
    Log.d(TAG, "Transaction Date: " + tr_date);
    Log.d(TAG, "Actual Balance: " + actual_balance);
    Log.d(TAG, "Available Balance: " + available_balance);
}
/**
 * Getting user SL details data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserSLDTL() {
    HashMap<String, String> sl_summ = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        sl_summ.put("sl_desc", cursor.getString(0));
        sl_summ.put("tr_date", cursor.getString(1));
        sl_summ.put("actual_balance", cursor.getString(2));
        sl_summ.put("available_balance", cursor.getString(3));

        Log.d(TAG, "Member's SL Details: " + sl_summ.toString());
    }
    else{
        Log.d(TAG, "member's SLDTL data is empty");
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Member's SL Details was successfully fetch: " + sl_summ.toString());

    return sl_summ;
}
```

Comment: Can you please read some tutorials regarding to database?

Comment: I can fetch the data sir but not using an adapter. I need an adapter so that I can display all the data inside my SQLite using a RecylerViewer.

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving you a sample code :-
If you are using String[] then you can replace List and ArrayList into String[].
I am just writing code using List.

you should fetch list of data first.

```
public List<HashMap<String, String>> getUserDetails() {
     HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
     List<HashMap<String,String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
     // write content values into HashMap
     // And add hashMap into List
     // userList.add(user);

     return userList;

}
```

And make a method in Adapter like this to notify Adapter :-

```
static void setList(List<HashMap> list) {

    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
        adapterList.addAll(list);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


List<HashMap<String,String>> userDetailList = getUserDetails();
```

Once you got data from DataBase then you can call

```
adapter.setList(userDetailList)
```

Note : all database operation should do in background thread.

Comment: I'm using string sir. Where should I put this code sir
public List<HashMap<String, String>> getUserDetails() {
     HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
     List<HashMap<String,String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
     // write content values into HashMap
     // And add hashMap into List
     // userList.add(user);

     return userList;

}?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you can create Members class like

You can change the data type of member variables as per your need:

```
public class  member
    {
        public int brachCode;
        public int mem_id;
        public String username;
        public String email;
        public Date crated_at;

        public int getBrachCode() {
            return brachCode;
        }

        public void setBrachCode(int brachCode) {
            this.brachCode = brachCode;
        }

        public int getMem_id() {
            return mem_id;
        }

        public void setMem_id(int mem_id) {
            this.mem_id = mem_id;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public Date getCrated_at() {
            return crated_at;
        }

        public void setCrated_at(Date crated_at) {
            this.crated_at = crated_at;
        }
    }
```

And change your SQliteHandler class method as below...

```
/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public List<Member> getUserDetails() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MEMBERS;
    List<Member>  mMemberDetails =  new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

         Member pMemebr = new Member();

         pMemebr.setBrachCode(cursor.getString(0));
         pMemebr.setMem(cursor.getString(1));
         pMemebr.setUsername(cursor.getString(2));
         pMemebr.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
         pMemebr.setCrated(cursor.getString(4));   

        mMemberDetails.add(pMemebr);    
        Log.d(TAG, "Members's data: " + user.toString());
    }
    else{
        Log.d(TAG, "member's data is empty");
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

return mMemberDetails;

}
```

in your MyAdapter classs change the constructor from this...

```
private String[] mDataset;
```

to this..

```
private List<Member> mDataset;

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }
```

to this...

```
 // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(List<Member>  mMemberDetails) {
        mDataset = mMemberDetails;
    }
```

and in  onBindViewHolder() change this line :

```
String currentValue = mDataset[position];
                Log.d("CardView", "CardView Clicked: " + currentValue);
```

to this...

```
// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(List<Member>  mMemberDetails) {
        mDataset = mMemberDetails;
    }
```

that's it. It will work now.

Comment: sir can you help me about fixing the error when I followed your code? I'm new to this Adapter and Android programming.

Comment: Sir Android Weblineindia, I followed your code. but it doesn't work. hope you will help me how to fix the error when I followed the code above.

Comment: Ok. Please check in your MyAdapter class. Initialize your mDataset variable like this : private List<Member> mDataset.   and in onBindViewHolder()  add mDataset.get(position).getEmail(). This will work.

Comment: public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset; -> it will generate an error Incompatible types.

Comment: I'm not an android developer I just followed some tutorials then post a question here if things do not go well.

Comment: Please try to change the constructor like:  public MyAdapter(List<Member>  mMemberDetails) {
        mDataset = mMemberDetails;
    }

Comment: already than sir. I change this public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
            mDataset = myDataset;
       } to this public MyAdapter(List<Member> mMemberDetails) { mDataset = mMemberDetails; }

Comment: the red line disappear but there's another problem sir. when I change this  line String currentValue = mDataset[position];
                Log.d("CardView", "CardView Clicked: " + currentValue); to this public MyAdapter(List<Member>  mMemberDetails) {
        mDataset = mMemberDetails;
    } it will generate an error.

Comment: Place your constructor properly. Why are you replacing String currentValue = mDataset[position]; Log.d("CardView", "CardView Clicked: " + currentValue); with the constructor with this line public MyAdapter(List<Member> mMemberDetails) { mDataset = mMemberDetails; } ?   In onBindViewHolder() just add: String currentValue = mDataset.get(position).getEmail();.

Comment: I just followed the instruction above sir. hehe.. sorry

Comment: In my AccountsFragment.ava sir it has an error in this line MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"test one", "test two"});
what should I do sir to fix this error?

Comment: First initialise the list in your in AccountsFragment.java like: List<Member> mData=new ArrayList();  and call the method getUserDetails() from SQliteHandler class  and add the result to the mData. And Add then add line :  MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(mData); now how you will call the method it is up to you.